# So, the expressions such as "in winters", "in Aprils", "on weekends", "at weekends", "in mornings" are right or not?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, usage

[Cambridge Grammar](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-time)

It says "**I’ve got to go to London on Friday**" (this Friday / next Friday -1 occasion)

but

"**The office is closed on Fridays**". (every Friday - repeated events)

It says "**I often get tired in the afternoon.**" (seem like "every afternoon")

but it says nothing about "**in afternoons**"

It says "**The garden is wonderful in the spring when all the flowers come out.**" (seem like "every Spring") but it says nothing about "**in Springs**"

It says "**We usually go camping in July or August.**" (seem like "every July" ) but it says nothing about "in Julies"

It says "**What do you usually do at the weekend (UK) / on the weekend (US)?**" but it says nothing about "at weekends" or "on weekends".

But [this site](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/weekend) says we can say "at weekends" or "on weekends". Ex: *I only see him at weekends.*

So, the expressions such as "**in winters**", "**in Aprils**", "**on weekends**", "**at weekends**", "**in mornings**" are right or not?

Answer (score 2):

Normally, when we use the temporal **summers, winters, evenings, mornings, days, nights, etc**, it is without the preposition **in**. The phrase "in the summer" can  mean *every* summer, winter, etc.

> Summers, we vacation at the beach.
>
> Winters, we vacation in the mountains.
>
> In the summer, we vacation at the beach.
>
> In the winter, we vacation in the mountains.
>
> In the summers, we ... <sup>unidiomatic, when the meaning is *every* summer</sup>

However, **in the summers** is idiomatic if the meaning is not "every summer" but a reference to multiple summers:

> Scientists have pulled core samples from Antartica revealing information about
>   the last five millenia there. **In the summers** where average temperatures were above 20C, there are large amounts of pollen.

[This may or may not be true. I just made the sentence up.]

We are likely to use **those** instead of **the** there, to reinforce the idea that we are pointing out a situation involving particular summers not every summer:

> In **those** summers where average temperatures were above 20C...

Comment: This site (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/summer) say "Be Careful!
Don't say that something happens 'in the summers' or 'in summers'."

Comment: Correct. We use the singular there, **in the *summer***, when the meaning is either "this summer" or "every summer", as my answer says. However, we can use the plural, **in the summers**, when we are referring to multiple discrete summers, not "every summer".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't come across any dialogue where I/someone else used 'in winters/Aprils' or 'at morning' (morning is a time of the day, idk how 'at' should even come across your mind)..

1) I love to play X-Box on weekends-- sounds correct to me.

similarly 'in mornings' seems fine as well.